# How to test the “random access bandwidth" of memory?

Tags: performance, memory, benchmarking, bandwidth, memory-bandwidth

I want to know how memory behave under a total random read workload. Usually, random access is simulated with [pointer chasing](https://panthema.net/2013/pmbw/index.html#description). However, this method may cause high dependency between two memory access instructions, which make the tested bandwidth limited by "instruction pipeline latency" instead of "memory channel bandwidth".

How could I test the memory bandwidth limitation under a random access workload?

Comment: The "memory channel" will have exactly the same bandwidth limits for random or structured all-read workloads.  The observed system throughput will be lower with random access workloads due to core limitations (address translation), hardware prefetch limitations, DRAM scheduling limitations, and DRAM timing restrictions.  Many of these limitations will depend on specific details of the "randomness" of the access pattern and how it maps onto the specific piece of hardware (including the extra pseudo-randomization of virtual to physical address translation for each execution of the code).

Comment: @JohnDMcCalpin Yes, these limitations are exactly what we care about the most. When I talk about “memory bandwidth”, I am not talking about the bandwidth of the memory channel, but the data bandwidth that upper-layer applications can feel when accessing memory.

Comment: Then why did you write "How could I test the **memory channel** bandwidth limitation under a random access workload?" as your 2nd paragraph?  But you actually want to test single-core random-read bandwidth for cache-miss loads?  That's what I assumed you meant when answering, until Dr. Bandwidth's comment got me thinking about what you actually wrote.  To test random reads for the memory controller, have all cores do random reads, or random NT stores.  (Maybe within a few DRAM "pages", aka rows, since there is that kind of locality in SDRAM addressing costing extra command overhead.)

Comment: I'm so sorry, this is a misphrasing on my part. I'll check out next time I ask a question. I apologize again for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

Use a fast PRNG like xorshift+ to generate random offsets into a big byte array.  (Use a power-of-2 array size so you can just mask the PRNG results to modulo them into the array range.)

Anything that defeats HW prefetch is sufficient; it doesn't have to be high-quality randomness.  Even an [LCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator) can be good enough, using implicit modulo 2^32 by using fixed-width integers, so you just have a multiply and add.  (On modern x86, that's 4-cycle critical-path latency.  Even with good memory-level parallelism, modern CPUs can't sustain 1 / 4-cycle throughput for loads that miss all the way to DRAM.)

But for smaller array sizes, where you're getting a lot of L2 hits, you might think about unrolling with two LCGs in parallel, to overlap their dependency chains.

---

If you specifically want to benchmark all cache misses, then a PRNG with period = array size (like an LCG using the power-of-2 array size as a modulus) could be better than higher-quality randomness where `random & (size-1)` will sometimes be the same location.  Period = size will give you a shuffle of element indices.  It won't avoid spatio-temporal locality entirely, though, so you'll still get some hits in some levels of cache, but not many.

You can make things harder for the cache by making it an array of 64-byte structs, so you only ever access each cache line once.  Or an array of `int` or `int64_t` instead of bytes, to reduce the amount of elements per cache line, and thus reduce the cache capacity if counting in elements instead of bytes.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I've tried with LCG generated random index. With 6364136223846793005UL for multiple and 1442695040888963407UL for add.
However, when I try to access 128B blocks in a 1TB memory region with 64B-aligned random address (address mask = 0xffffffffc0), the L3 miss rate remain at about 78%,   which is higher than expected. Since 1TB is much larger than L3 size, how could I make it achieve a higher miss rate, like 99%?

Comment: @Frontier_Setter: Those parameters should produce a max-length period (m).  If you use a 64-bit LCG (m = 2^64) and then mask its results (not m=2^40 or whatever), the low bits could possibly repeat more often.  But probably the repeating patterns in low bits phenomenon is mostly limited to the lowest bits, the ones you're masking off.  So the bits you keep should be random-ish.  But how are you reading 128 bytes?  Could that be producing L3 hits on the second line sometimes?  Your code makes no other memory accesses?

Comment: I'm reading 128 byte with 5 vmovdqa instructions

Comment: If you're going to read 128 bytes, keep in mind that the L2 spatial prefetcher will try to complete 128-byte *aligned* pairs of cache lines.  So touching two adjacent cache lines that aren't 128-byte aligned may sometimes result in extra fetches to complete those pairs in L2.  But five `vmovdqa` instructions?  Why an odd number, that seems really weird?

Comment: I deeply apologize for being a bit overwhelmed by this issue these days. As you pointed out, the correct scenario involves 4 vmovdqa instructions. Following your valuable advice, I attempted to disable all prefetching related option in the BIOS, including “L1 Stream HW Prefetcher”、“L1 Stride/Region Prefetcher”、“L2 Stream HW Prefetcher”、“L2 Up/Down Prefetcher” and "L1 Burst Prefetch Mode", but unfortunately, there was no change. The LLC miss rate still remains below 80%. I am using an AMD machine.

Comment: @Frontier_Setter: IDK, I'd expect a random access pattern to work, even if you do groups of loads with lots of locality.  But the obvious thing to try would be only one load from each random location, not four, to see if that makes a difference.  (i.e. if the locality of those sequential loads was creating hits sometimes.)  Or if your code does any other memory accesses that might be generating L3 hits; I assume your PRNG and loop stuff is purely in registers, or at least would hit in L1d so not have to access L3 at all.  I guess a new question might make sense, rather than an edit to this one

Comment: @Frontier_Setter - since you have a target system and a set of observed miss rates, I would recommend trying to run the address stream against a cache model.  Before that I would recommend doing some experiments to test the performance counters you are using and investigate what other counters might be available to help characterize the cache behavior. Note that the system behavior, the definitions of the performance counters, and the (possible) set of errors in the performance counters will be processor model-dependent.